# Recursive method that prints the digits of the number line by line

Tags: java, methods, recursion, numbers, integer

I'm supposed to use a recursive method to print out the digits of a number vertically.

For example, if I were to key in 13749, the output would be:

```
1
3
7
4
9
```

How should I approach this question?? It also states that I should use the if/else method to check for the base case.. I just started learning java and I'm not really good at it :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {
  public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(numbers(n));  

  } 

public static int numbers(int n){
  int sum;
  if (n == 0) {
    sum = 1;
    } else {

     System.out.println(n%10);
     sum = numbers(n / 10) + (n % 10);


    }
  return sum;
  }      
}
```

Comment: Nice homework. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you've been given examples of recursion to learn off of. Why not first have another look at them, and then give this a try?

Comment: @user2765163: please post all question updates and code as an edit to your original question. We cannot read code in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code in C++

Just modify it for Java. You need to show the number after you call the function that way you show the last one first... as per the answer from s.ts

```
void recursive(int n) {
    if (n < 10)
        cout << n << endl;
    else
    {
        recursive(n / 10);
        cout << n % 10 << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was asked this question today in an interview!

```
 public class Sandbox {
   static void prints(int d) {
        int rem = d % 10;
        if (d == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            prints(d / 10);
        }
        System.out.println(rem);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prints(13749);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
7
4
9
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to approach this, so I'll give you a tip: it would be a lot easier to build up the stack **and then** start printing output. It also doesn't involve manipulating strings, which is a big plus in my book. The order of operations would be:

1. Check for base case and return if it is
2. Recursive call
3. Print

This way when you get to the base case, you'll start printing from the tail to the head of the calls:

```
recursive call 1
    recursive call 2
        recursive call 3
            .... reached base case
        print 3
    print 2
print 1
```

This way you can simply print number % 10 and make the recursive call with number / 10, the base case would be when number is 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
class PrintDigits {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String originalNumber, reverse = "";

     // Creating an Scanner object
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Enter a number:");
     // Reading an input 
     originalNumber = in.nextLine();

     // Calculating a length
     int length = originalNumber.length();

     // Reverse a given number
     for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
        reverse = reverse + originalNumber.charAt(i);
     //System.out.println("Reverse number: "+reverse);
     digits(Integer.parseInt(reverse));
   }

   /* digits of num */
   public static void digits(int number) {
       if (number == 0)
          System.out.println("");
       else {
          int mode=10;
          System.out.println(+number%mode);
          digits(number/mode);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even compile. I think you mean `System.out.printf` instead of `System.out.println` in method digits. And in the same method `return dsigits(number/mode);` how can you return something from a `void` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
If number consists of more than one digit print ( n / 10 )

print ( n % 10 )
```

If you want them printed in the other order

```
print ( n % 10 )

If number consists of more than one digit print ( n / 10 )
```

Comment: Wrong. The digits should not be in reverse order. :)

Comment: But how do I make them come out in order?? I tried editing my code a few times but it keeps coming out in reverse hahaha

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Digits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDigits(13749);
    }

    private static void printDigits(Integer number) {
        int[] m = new int[number.toString().toCharArray().length];

        digits(number, 0, m, 0);

        for (int i= m.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(m[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int digits(int number, int reversenumber, int[] m, int i) {

        if (number <= 0) {
            return reversenumber;
        }

        m[i] = (number % 10);
        reversenumber = reversenumber * 10 + (number % 10);
        return digits(number/10, reversenumber, m, ++i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python example

```
def printNoVertically(number):
    if number <  9:
      print(number)
      return
    else:
        printNoVertically(number/10)
        print(number % 10)
```